# Spring security per request with custom AUTH token in header

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security in my app. On that I have to use custom token(which is stored in DB mapped with user) to secure REST API.

This is my web security configuration.

```
@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery()).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
}
```

Above code is my global auth config.

```
@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserRoleManager userRolePage;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        List<RolePageMap> rolePageMaps = userRolePage.getRolePageMapList();

        for (RolePageMap rolePageMap : rolePageMaps) {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(rolePageMap.getAccessablePages().getPageValue())
                    .access("hasRole('" + rolePageMap.getUserRole().getRoleName() + "')");
        }

        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/successMessage.html")
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(customAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                final String customToken = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
                if (csrf != null && customToken == null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private Filter customAuthFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
                if(token != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin");
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

}
```

Note: In above code I have used two filters in a same security configuration.

The intention of that config is, If the custom token exist in header we should use the corresponding filter, if it is not there in request then it should validate the CSRF token.

Here the problem is If the custom exist then it is worked and when I removed the header and the call the API again it return the results but it should not.

Is this a correct approach to achieve this security>

Can someone help me on this?